# Sort list based on another?

Tags: c#, linq

I've got two generic lists with two different types stored:

```
class A {
    public int id;
    //...
}
class B {
    public int id;
    //...
}
```

They share a similar property, id. Now one list has a certain order of objects and their ids and the second one has totally different order of ids:

```
List<A> listA; // the ids of objects inside go as follows: 4, 5, 1
List<B> listB; // the ids of objects inside go as follows: 1, 4, 5
```

I'd like to sort listB so that `listB[0].id==listA[0].id`, `listB[1].id==listA[1].id` etc. Thought about using `Join` but no idea what to put in `OrderBy`.

Comment: Why don't you create a class `Mother` with an ID, make your two classes inherit from it then sort by it?

Comment: `listB[1].id==listA[2].id` shouldn't that be `listB[1].id==listA[1].id` ?

Comment: @Nasreddine yes, fixed, thx

Comment: Also, what happens when `ListA` has an item with an `Id` that is not present in `ListB`? You can't just go from `ListB[1]` to `ListB[4]` for example and for that reason you should just `OrderBy(x => x.id)` both lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily create anonymous objects containing the required index and then sort by this index:

```
var result = listB.Select((b, index) => 
                     new {Index = listA.FindIndex(a => a.id == b.id),
                          B = b})
                  .OrderBy(b => b.Index)
                  .Select(b => b.B).ToList();
```

So the first `Select` creates a sequence of objects containing the `Index` of the matching element in `listA`.
This sequence is then ordered by that index and the final `Select` gives out the instances from `listB` in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through `List<A>` item by item, find the corresponding `B` item in the source instance of `List<B>` and store it into another, destination instance of `List<B>`. And you are done.

```
List<B> destinationListB = new List<B>();
foreach (A in listA)
{
    B b = listB.FirstOrDefault(item => item.id = A.id);
    if (b != nul) destinationListB.Add(b);
}
```

*Disclaimer: There might be a more time-efficient solution.*

Answer (score 0):

[List.FindIndex()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is your friend:

```
var orderedB = listB.OrderBy(b => listA.FindIndex(a => a.id == b.id));
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CpLeFU